# Delete top X rows with a table with composite key using NHibernate

Tags: sql, nhibernate

We have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE TagValueDouble(
    TagIdentity [int] NOT NULL,
    TimestampInUtcTicks [bigint] NOT NULL,
    DoubleValue [float] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_TagValueDouble] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    TagIdentity ASC,
    TimestampInUtcTicks ASC
)
```

This table gets filled up with many measurements from different sources (e.g wind speed). The TagIdentity, represents the source, combined with the timestamp represents a unique record.

This table gets large, say 2000 different sources with a 2Hz update rate.

Not often but sometimes we remove a source and we need to drop all the records of that source in the table. The problem is that using NHibernate the query times out.

My plan was to delete X rows at a time of records that are no longer part of the system. Something in the lines of:

```
DELETE FROM TagValueDouble 
WHERE TagIdentity in
(SELECT TOP 10 TagIdentity, TimestampInUtcTicks
  FROM TagValueDouble
  Where TagIdentity not in (12, 14))
```

But this does not work.

Any ideas on how I can clean up the table without risking the timeout?

I'm looking for stability not performance. Deleting all values for a source is something that is done rarely.

PS. It has to work on SQL Server, Oracle, Posgres and SQL CE.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing the index on TagIdentity. Create the index en make sure it is filled correctly before deleting the records.

Comment: There is an index on the primary key; TagIdentity, TimestampInUtcTicks. So I do not believe finding the records is what taking so long. But I will try it.

Comment: You should check the fill and fragmentation of the index. If there are a lot new records it is likely the index will not work and you have to re calculate the index before deleting.

Comment: What if the table was partitioned on TagIdentity? Or do you have a suggestion on how to delete a subset at a time.

Answer (score 0):

One idea was to do something like this:

```
DELETE FROM TagValueDouble
WHERE (TagIdentity + 4000) * 315360000000000 + TimestampInUtcTicks IN
(SELECT TOP 1000 (TagIdentity + 4000) * 315360000000000 + TimestampInUtcTicks 
 FROM TagValueDouble
 WHERE TagIdentity NOT IN (5, 10, 12, 13))
```

Rationale beeing that I do not expect the system to be running in the year 4000. So I combine the TagIdentity and TimestampInUtcTicks to one unique value. But this ended up checking all entires in the table.

What I ended up with was querying for one value which was not in the "allowed" TagIdentity set. And then delete any value from that values timestamp and 24 hours back in time. If that query also timed out, reduce the number of hours until deletion succeeds. Doing this job until no more values where found cleans up the database.